# How to use split() to separate and display a text file to calculate and average

Tags: python, split

I'm having trouble with the `split()` function.  I have a module named `printReport()` that contains a name and 3 test scores in each line.  I need to split the data so the names and scores can be displayed and have the average calculated.  I'm positive I'm trying to do this completely wrong. I'm getting an `IndexError: list index out of range.` This is only the start of my problem.  I still have no idea how to do the calculations and be displayed like below.

> ---
>
> Student Name     Score 1     Score 2     Score 3     Total
>
> ---
>
> Dave               82          91          77         250
>
> Tom                79          22          84         185
>
> Dick               67          22          91         180
>
> ---
>
> Mon Feb 8 15:12:08 2016

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I would fix it.

```
    ### Subprogram detStudentData(fn, scores)

    def getStudentData(fn, scores):
        #   Writes instructions for the user to follow
        print("Enter the student names and scores following the prompts below.")
        print("To finish entering student names, enter: ZZZ.\n")

        #   Set the flag for the loop
        done = False
        #   Loop to get input from the usere
        while done != True:

            #   Creates a newFile and enables append
            newFile = open(fn, "a")
            #   Asks for a student name and assigns it to student_name
            student_name = input("Please enter the student name (ZZZ to finish): ")
            #   Compairs student_name to see if it is equal to "ZZZ"
            if student_name == "ZZZ":
                #   Sets the flag to True to exit the loop
                done = True
            #   Asks for test scores if student_name is not equal "ZZZ"
            else:
                #   Asks for test score 1 and assigns it to test_1
                test_1 = input("Enter score 1: ")
                #   Asks for test score 2 and assigns it to test_2
                test_2 = input("Enter score 2: ")
                #   Asks for test score 3 and assigns it to test_3
                test_3 = input("Enter score 3: ")
                print("\n")

                newFile.write(student_name) #  Writes student_name to newFile
                newFile.write(", ")         #  Writes "," to newFile
                newFile.write(test_1)       #  Writes test_1 to newFile
                newFile.write(", ")         #  Writes "," to newFile
                newFile.write(test_2)       #  Writes test_2e to newFile
                newFile.write(", ")         #  Writes "," to newFile
                newFile.write(test_3)       #  Writes test_3 to newFile
                newFile.write("\n")         #  Wites a return to newFile

            #   Closes newFile
            newFile.close()
    # ==============================================================================

    ### Subprogram getTextFileContents(fn)

    def getTextFileContents(fn):
        #   Opens the file and enables read
        with open(fn, "r") as ins:
            #   Splits the text file before the ","
            list = fn.split(",")

            #   Creates a loop to load the characters into a list
            for line in ins:
                #   Appends the text to list
                list.append(line)

        # Returns the value in list
        return list


    # ==============================================================================

    ### Subprogram printReport(line)

    def printReport(line):
        #   Prints the heading to show the test scores
        print("__________________________________________________________")
        print("Student Name     Score 1     Score 2     Score 3     Total")
        print("----------------------------------------------------------")

        name = []       #   Declare name a list
        test1 = []      #   Declare test1 a list
        test2 = []      #   Declare test2 a list
        test3 = []      #   Declare test a list

        with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                name.append(line.split(",", 1)[0])
            line = name[0]
            capacity = len(name)
            index = 0
            while index != capacity:
                line = name[index]
                for nameOut in line.split():
                    print(nameOut)
                    index = index + 1

        # ================================================

        with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                test1.append(line.split(",", -1)[1])
            line = test1[1]
            capacity = len(test1)
            index1 = 0
            while index1 != capacity:
                line = test1[index1]
                for t1Out in line.split():
                    print(t1Out)
                    index1 = index1 + 1

        # ================================================

        with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                test2.append(line.split(",", -1)[2])
            line = test2[2]
            capacity = len(test2)
            index2 = 0
            while index2 != capacity:
                line = test2[index2]
                for t2Out in line.split():
                    print(t2Out)
                    index2 = index2 + 1

        # ================================================

        with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                test3.append(line.split(" ", -1)[3])
            line = test3[3]
            capacity = len(test3)
            index3 = 0
            while index != capacity:
                line = test3[index3]
                for t3Out in line.split():
                    print(t3Out)
                    index3 = index3 + 1

    # ==============================================================================
    def main():


        fn = "grades.txt"               #   set the working file name
        scores = 3                      #   set the number of scores
        getStudentData(fn, scores)      #   Calls getStudentData()
        line = getTextFileContents(fn)  #   Assigns getTextFileContent() to line
        printReport(line)               #   Calls printReport()

    main()
```

Comment: What errors do you get? You'd need to add that in. It's possible to determine the issue without having to run your code.

Comment: I'm getting an IndexError: list index out of range in line 137

Comment: Need the complete traceback with line and line number.

Comment: here: `list = fn.split(",")` you are splitting the file name not the content?

Comment: If you're getting an index error after splitting a line on ',' then maybe you're making assumptions about your test file that aren't true (i.e. there aren't always commas on every line that you thought there were?).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
----------------------------------------------------------
Dave
  File "S:/CSN/3. Summer 2017/IS115 - Intro to Programming/Programs/Chapter 10/A10.py", line 156, in <module>
Tom
    main()
Dick
82
79
  File "S:/CSN/3. Summer 2017/IS115 - Intro to Programming/Programs/Chapter 10/A10.py", line 154, in main
67
    printReport(line)               #   Calls printReport()
91
22
96
  File "S:/CSN/3. Summer 2017/IS115 - Intro to Programming/Programs/Chapter 10/A10.py", line 137, in printReport
    line = test3[3]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @jprockbelly.  I'm just learning this today.  Therefore, I'm not surprised I'm getting it wrong.  I'm sure the video I watch was wrong.  They explained that list = fn.split(",") was to separate the list.  How would I separate the content correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Check the lines

```
line = test1[1]
line = test2[2]
line = test3[3]
```

You should start the list from `0`, not `1`, `2`, `3`

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed my error problem. For some reason, I was thinking I need to put the index number of where they were in the element of text.

Comment: Now, my next question would be, is there a way to join them together so the persons name is displayed on the same line as their 3 grades?

Comment: Ah, totally missed that! Good catch. I think the other errors pointed out in my answer would still cause issues at some point, but wasn't the immediate issue.

Comment: @Mike, try doing it all within the one `with open...` block. To join a list of string elements you can do something like `'\t'.join(list_of_strings_to_join)`, which in this case creates a tab-separated output.

Comment: @Andrew, I deleted all the with open ... except for the 1st one.  Now, only the 3 names are displayed.  Also, when I added print("\t".join(nameOut, t1Out, t2Out, t3Out)) to the end of the module, I get this error. line 138, in printReport print("\t".join(nameOut, t1Out, t2Out, t3Out))  UnboundLocalError: local variable 't1Out' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Mike, obviously there is more that will need to be done to properly implement this. My suggestion was just to get you started. You will need to define `t1out` etc within each loop. Then once these are defined, you can join them and print.

Comment: @Andrew. Thanks.  I'm making slow progress.  I just think my logic is flawed and there is probably a better way for me to handle splitting the data from the text file, calculating the average and then printing it to the screen.  I was thinking about trying to load the text file into a multidimensional array.  However, I'm not sure how to convert the grades to integers in the array.  I've read on here how to convert the entire array but not how to convert specific elements of the array.

Comment: @Mike, I've thrown together a rough template of how I would approach this. You can find it here - https://codeshare.io/5Mey4W Note the use of a **list comprehension** to turn all the grades into floats ready for calculating the average. There's plenty of tutorials on google if you don't understand how this works.

Comment: @AndrewGuy . Thank you. I really appreciate it. I'm sure it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The offending section is this:

```
        while index != capacity:
            line = test3[index3]
            for t3Out in line.split():
                print(t3Out)
                index3 = index3 + 1
```

The first line should be:

```
while index3 != capacity:
```

Note that manually incrementing an index is probably not the best way to loop over a list in Python. A more pythonic way might be something like:

```
for item in test3:
    for t3out in item.split():
         print(t3out)
```

Also, if you're going to stick with incrementing manually, you need to remove the `index = index + 1` from inside the for loop. You should only increment after processing each line.

```
        while index != capacity:
            line = test3[index3]
            for t3Out in line.split():
                print(t3Out)
            index3 = index3 + 1
```

Comment: Thank You.  I've corrected that but I'm still getting an IndexError: list index out of range in line 137 line = test3[3]

Comment: Sorry, missed the other obvious error. You will probably need to edit each of your `while` loops. Really, you should just drop the manual indexing and use a `for` loop to loop over all items in the list.

Comment: 5.  Thanks.  I will do that.  I only used it because that is what they used in the videos I watched while trying to learn how to do this today.  However, a For loop makes more sense.

Comment: I changed all the while loops to For loops.  Now, it is error free with all your help.  Is there a way for me to print the name and 3 scores on the same line?